# Interpretation of cloglog model in layman's terms

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, link-function, beta-regression

I fitted a beta regression model via MCMC with a complementary log-log link function.  Is there a way to interpret it in a layman's terms?

The estimates of the model are:

\begin{align}
\beta_0 &= -1.12     &\beta_1 &= -0.142     &\beta_2 &= 0.127  \\
 \eta_0 &= -3.22      &\eta_1 &=  0.72       &\eta_2 &= 0.87
\end{align}

The response variable is the proportion of income spent on children's education, $X_1$ is the family income, and $X_2$ is the number of sons.

The $\beta$'s are associated with the mean parameter of the distribution and the $\eta$'s with the dispersion parameter.

I already read this topic [interpreting estimates of cloglog logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132627/interpreting-estimates-of-cloglog-logistic-regression), but I think that that interpretation is not appropriate.

Comment: What exactly is not appropriate for you in the second question?

Comment: @Tim I think that the interpretation of parameters as hazard ratios not make sense for this problem, since it's not related with survival analysis.

Comment: @Roland I'm not aware of a "nice" interpretation that works in beta regression models. One could say, in your case, that the log-proportion _not_ spent on children's education increases by about 13% per son. But this is clearly less intuitive than the log-survival from Glen_b's answer.