# Interpreting a binomial regression model in R with cloglog link function

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have built a binomial regression model using the equation:

```r
logit_1 <- glm(past_adl_binary~., family = binomial(link = "cloglog"), 
               data = newdata)
```

The outcome of the model is as follows: [image]

Can anyone help me interpret the outcome of this model? I understand that all of the coefficients are significant apart from sunangle.

Can I use this equation `(100*exp(parameter estimate)-1)` to calculate the increase/ decrease in percent probability of my y-variable (1 or 0) changing based on my predictor variables?  For example, for `habitat_categoryONDEEP: 100*(exp(-0.173)-1) = -15.886`.  Would this suggest that a habitat category of `ONDEEP` decreases the probability of my y-variable being 1 by 15.9%, compared to the reference category?

Comment: The size of the AIC is irrelevant: all that matters are differences between the AICs of related models. In fact, different software platforms may report different values of AIC for a given model and dataset!

Comment: The cloglog link does **not** follow the rule of thumb that you state above; it works on the *log-hazard* scale: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132627/interpreting-estimates-of-cloglog-logistic-regression (this might get closed as a duplicate of that answer)